# Android Bypass Captive Portal

Tags: android, android-wifi

I'd like the user's of my Android app to be able to connect to a captive network without having to launch a browser to accept the terms of service.

Is there something like iOS CaptiveNetwork for Android?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to all the different captive portal installations, you'll never be able to work this out reliably.  Apple's doesn't work half the time either and in most cases ends up launching a browser for the user, which then takes them to the captive portal page to agree/login/etc.

Make your app launch a browser if it can't gain connectivity (or because the captive portal is redirecting it's traffic, it isn't getting the expected response) You might want to check a dedicated file that is unique to your app, for example GET http://www.example.com/check/captive.htm if the file contents is "success" then you're good, if the file results in anything else then assume your behind a captive portal and launch a browser - that's the right way to handle it.

Comment: That is too bad to hear, it's kind of a major issue in my mind, especially for companies who want their customer's to reliably be able to use their apps indoors on a wi-fi network with captive portal.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking up this question as a user, not a developer, there are several apps now on Google Play to help you from a user perspective. For developers: some of these also offer APIs for use in other apps.
Some examples:

- WiFi Web Login
- WiFi AfterConnect Web Login
- Captivate (shows login screen, not auto login)

And to get round the latest version of Android disconnecting wifi when captive portal is detected, try this app: Wifi Portal Connect. This will then work together with one of the apps suggested above to reconnect to wifi and then the other apps will be able to auto-login.

Every captive portal is different, so bear this in mind, its not the apps fault if it ends up not working, but apps are getting better at being flexible and auto detecting systems, so try a few.